# How to edit SQL permissions for 365 group user

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL DB. I need to give a Azure group permissions to do select statements to get data out of this DB, but it's important they can't do anything to mess it up with delete/update etc.

I created a SQL user from a 365 group with

```
CREATE USER [GroupName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

, but now these group members have permission to do update/delete commands etc. I only want these group members to be able to do select statements. However...

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'GroupName'
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [GroupName]
```

gives the error:

```
Cannot alter the role 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Why is this? I would assume I need to revoke the current permissions anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure it out so I just deleted the user and created from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are grating permission to **Azure Active Directory Group**.

Use the below statements and it should work fine.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'Azure Active Directory Group'

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::<schema_name> TO [Azure Active Directory Group]
```

**Note:** Make sure you have required permission on the schema level to grant the required permission. Please see the permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions).